# Time complexity of a function in Big-O

Tags: c, big-o, time-complexity

I'm trying to find the time complexity of this function:

```
int bin_search(int a[], int n, int x); // Binary search on an array with size n.

int f(int a[], int n) {
    int i = 1, x = 1;
    while (i < n) {
        if (bin_search(a, i, x) >= 0) {
            return x;
        }
        i *= 2;
        x *= 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**The answer is (log n)^2. How come?**

 Best I could get is `log n`. First the `i` is `1`, so the while will be run `log n` times.
At first interaction, when `i=1`, the binary search will have only one interaction because the array's size is 1(i). Then, when `i=2`, two interactions, and so on until it's `log n` interactions.

 So the formula I thought would fit is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk9cl.gif).

 The summation is for the while and the inner equation is because for `i=1` it's `log(1)`, for `i=2` it's `log(2)` and so on until it's `log(n)` at the last.


Where am I wrong?

Comment: You forgot to simplify. `log(n / 2^i) = log(n) - i`. When you sum that `log(n)` times you get the the answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller God. You're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each iteration performs a binary search on the first `2^i` elements of the array.

You can compute the number of operations (comparisons):

```
log2(1) + log2(2) + log2(4) + ... + log2(2^m)
```

`log(2^n)` equals `n`, so this series simplifies into:

```
0 + 1 + 2 + ... + m
```

Where `m` is `floor(log2(n))`.

The series evaluates to `m * (m + 1) / 2`, replacing `m` we get

```
floor(log2(n)) * (floor(log2(n)) + 1) / 2

->  0.5 * floor(log2(n))^2 + 0.5 * floor(log2(n))
```

The first element dominates the second, hence the complexity is `O(log(n)^2)`